# Convert TFS field type from string to plain text

Tags: tfs

i have a TFS field that was defined as string. I realized that the field may have more than 255 characters and hence would like to change it to plain text. When I tried doing so with witcommands, it gave an error saying that the field is not supported. Is there a way this can be done? I cannot delete this field and create a new one as it has thousands of records.

Answer (score 2):

If you type `witadmin changefield /?` you get

```
/type      The new type of the field. Only conversion between Html and PlainText is supported.
```

But wait, there is way to do it via a series of `witadmin` commands:

1. Add a new temporary field
2. Copy the data from the existing one
3. Drop the old field
4. Rename the temporary field to match the name of the old one

I did this a couple of times so I know it works